# Error while indexing in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1

I am trying to reindex the data in magento via SSH i have memory_limit = 1024M.
But when i try to reindex the data it stopped suddenly and Killed comes written on screen. I have imported near about 50000 products . Before import, indexing was fine. 
Please answer if anybody already been through this kind of error.

Thanks

Comment: what is the message you got in you SSH terminal?

Comment: In the next line of SSH terminal the only message written is  "Killed".

Comment: and this comes not from Magento. at least not from its generic part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer on stackoverflow might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726762/387136).
Basically it means that the PHP process doing the indexing exceeds the memory limit you have on the server and it's killed by linux to prevent crashing the server

50K products is a lot and I'm not surprised it's causing issue when running the indexer under only 1024M of memory. The only solution will be to upscale your server or use an Amazone cloud instance for example to do the heavy lifting

Comment: Hello Marius and Sander i traced down the whole configurations of server and the increased the max_execution_time to 18000 and now i am able to re-index the data. Thanks a ton for your guidance.

Comment: Hi Sarvagy, I hope you only did that for this one specific script and not for the default execution time?

Comment: Hello Sander, i have set this at php.ini of my server and .htaccess of my website . i did anything wrong ??

Comment: A default execution time of 300 minutes can potentially be an issue for your server. When a page loads extremely slow you want to timeout to kick in and prevent the server from having long processes it can't handle. I would suggest using the shell script for reindexing through the commandline and setting the timeout back